# Azure VM - List Creator / Created By Detail?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

I use Azure powershell to spin VMs in Azure. However there are so many people with me who do the same thing in the same subscription. All use powershell only for spinning the vms. I want to find out who has created which VM. Unfortunately we don't see any created by detail using Powershell (N.B. I use ASM approach for creating vms)-

`Get-AzureVm "xxx" "yyy"`

I am trying out to figure out a way to find out which VM is created by which person. I do think there is something in `Azure Portal > Management Services > Operation Logs` where I can see the operations performed by different users. But I prefer PowerShell so that I can use some logic and automate some kind of mechanism which can provide me a detail for the same with minimal effort. How this can be achieved?

Comment: The Operation Logs are not an option if you want to find out, who created a resource - a VM - month ago, as they are only kept for 90 days. I also searched quite excessively but couldn't find a property that names the account that created either an Azure resource.